# How to test Firebase Auth Blocking functions V2 locally on the emulator?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

On the Firebase Console there is an option in settings that allows you to choose which function to trigger (screenshot belows) for the 2 events beforeUserCreated & beforeUserSignedIn. Looking at David's [video on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQPukA6WjVw) I see that I need to export them in my functions index file and then after deployment they show up in the dropdown in settings and thats where you select which function to trigger for each event.

In the Emulator there is no such setting, so how do I tell the Auth Emulator to trigger beforeUserCreated & beforeUserSignedIn for the users?

Thanks!

[image]
[image: Code]

[image: Firebase Settings]

Comment: Have you tried to just run them without any special setting in the emulator? There is plenty of evidence out there of people using blocking functions in the emulator. If you don't see a setting for it, maybe there just isn't one, and the functions just work as you would expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson tried below and it worked!

     const {
       beforeUserCreated,
       beforeUserSignedIn,
     } = require("firebase-functions/v2/identity");

     exports.beforeUserCreated =           beforeUserCreated((event) => {
       console.log( event.data);
     });
     exports.beforeUserSignedIn =      beforeUserSignedIn((event) => {
       const user = event.data;
       console.log(user);
     });
For people who end up here: If you use V1 auth blocking function triggers and then V2 you need to restart the emulator else it doesn't take in the V2 and throws errors.

Answer (score 0):

**For those who end up here upon searching:**

You do not need to export the blocking function as constant, it works without it (I wonder why they make you select in production though).

Also a note: If you use V1 blocking functions and then switch to V2 then you need to restart the emulator else it throws all kinds of errors which are confusing and hard to figure out.

Below is what I ended up doing:

[image]